# PHP CURL Error : Data returning NULL Value

Tags: php, json, curl, foreach

I have a JSON code which I put in JSON file named data.json

the JSON Code is :

```
[
 {"value":"23","date":"03/2018"},
 {"value":"43","date":"03/2019"},
 {"value":"34","date":"12/2017"},
 {"value":"13","date":"01/2019"},
 {"value":"34","date":"02/2019"}
]
```

Now The php Code I am using to fetch the data is as Follows :

```
$url = "data.json" ;

$ch = curl_init() ;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch) ;


$data = json_decode($result, true) ;

foreach($data as $mydata)
{
  $data1 = $mydata["value"] ;
  $data2 = $mydata["date"] ;

echo $data1 ." : ". $data2 ;
echo "<br/>";

}
```

I Don't understand what's wrong with the code but it gives an error Warning

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

This Happens Because the Data is returning **NULL** Value But I Don't How my JSON Data Format is not correct.
THe Format Looks Fine. But it still returns NULL Value.

Comment: Are you getting data in $data?

Comment: What is `console.log($result);` giving you?

Comment: var_dump $data to see what is in there - when I use your json directly it works for me

Comment: can you dump the variable $mydata please and show us

Comment: Var_dump( $data) gives me NULL Result @rapaelec  But why ?

Comment: foreach is wrong as well, it should be foreach($data as $key => $value)

Comment: @B001ᛦ No typo, he wants key and value, foreach should have key and value for next lines of code $data1 = $mydata["value"] ;
  $data2 = $mydata["date"] ;

Comment: I Have Changed the question Title and Description . please let me know Why I am getting this error

Comment: this json file is located in your server? why are you using cUrl and bot file_get_contents ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct url?

Comment: @shushu304 There may be a chance I may use this content from external url that's why I am using cURL

Comment: @B001ᛦ yes , both the files are in the same Folder

Comment: @abnit-chauhan it a waste to use cUrl for local file, try to change to use file_get_contents in case it's local file, and use curl in case it's an url/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the full URL of the JSON file if you are using `CURL`, instead of the `data.json`

```
http://localhost/text.json
```

other options to get the data from json

```
$result = file_get_contents($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.Please check.

```
<?php
      $url = "http://raveesh.rnd/data.json" ;
      $ch = curl_init() ;

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url) ;
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch) ;

      $data = json_decode($result, true) ;

      foreach($data as $mydata)
      {
           $data1 = $mydata["value"] ;
           $data2 = $mydata["date"] ;

           echo $data1 ." : ". $data2 ;
           echo "<br/>";
      }
?>

Output:

 23 : 03/2018
 43 : 03/2019
 34 : 12/2017
 13 : 01/2019
 34 : 02/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

The probleme here is :

1- you can't curl the same host , you must use function **file_get_content()** to get your json like :

```html
<?php

$string = file_get_contents("./data.json");
$data = json_decode($string, true);



foreach($data as $mydata)
{
  $data1 = $mydata["value"] ;
  $data2 = $mydata["date"] ;

echo $data1 ." : ". $data2 ;
echo "<br/>";

}
```

if you want to use curl , it must be another host like:

```html
<?php

$url = "http://date.jsontest.com" ;

$ch = curl_init($url) ;

$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json')
);

curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch) ;

$result = json_decode($result, 1);


foreach($result as $key => $mydata)
{
    echo $key ." : ". $mydata ;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

so it depend of the structural of your Json

thanks

Answer (score -1):

when using cUrl with file name only, the cUrl think that it's an url so you will got error

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host
```

if it's a local file, i will prefer to use file_get_contents...

```
$json = file_get_contents("file.json");
put here your json decode and logic
```

and in case of url to use the curl.

to answer and help you, let's try to see if you got any errors from curl...

change the code like that and update us

try to use curl_error and check if there are any errors from cUrl,

what you get?

```
$url = "data.json" ;
$ch = curl_init() ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch) ;

if (isset($error_msg)) {
    // TODO - Handle cURL error accordingly
}

// put here your json decode and logic
```

Comment: I got what I am doing wrong. When I add full URL path in the $url . I am able to fetch the data. But do you Know the Reason why ?

Comment: i'm trying to help... first check what the errors ... and then we will update and continue help you

Comment: Thanks for the help . I didn't downvote your answer. but may be your reason is correct. The use of curl when its needed is the best practice

Comment: please try this, and let's continue to figure it out. and you are welcome to upvote :)

Comment: I upvoted,  but my votes doesn't count. Let me try this example out